# Converting a regular expression to a grammar and regular grammar

Tags: regular-expressions, formal-grammar

I tried looking around for help before posting this but either the question did not match mine or I was not able to understand the answer posted due to my lack of knowledge.

I am working on a lab and it requires us to take the following regex for a float:

$$[0-9].[0-9]+e(-)?[0-9]$$

I have the three following steps:

1. Regex into regular definition
2. regular definition into grammar
3. Grammar into regular grammar

We have some examples in our lectures but I can't seem to understand how to do these steps, I have done some work for step 1 but I doubt it's correct.

**Part 1:**

$[0-9] \rightarrow Number$

$"." \rightarrow Decimal$

$e \rightarrow Exponent$

$"-" \rightarrow Negative$

Regular Definition: Number Decimal Number+ Exponent Negative? Number+

What I understood from my lecture slides was that we are naming parts of the regex and then rewriting it using the names we choose, although I've probably missed some major step here.

**Part 2:**

I don't know how to progress past this step, this step depends on the work from my last step so I'm hesitant to even attempt it. I have reviewed some of the material I have for grammar but I couldn't fully understand how it works. If anyone has any material that they found helpful in understanding grammar/regular grammar I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like your question is not very well suited for this site. It might be better suited for cs.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thank you, I assumed it was more math based but I will post to one of the other places you mentioned to hopefully get some answers